# How can I italicize a list of names and plot them in R?

Tags: r, plot

I can italicize a phrase when plotting text like this:
 `text(1, 2, substitute(paste(italic('Gorilla gorilla gorilla'))`,
however, I want to send a whole list of names to text but of course the following won't work
 `text(x-coordinates, y-coordinates, substitute(paste(italic('list'))`,
as it will just plot "list" repeatedly.
Is there a work around?

I have tried to italicize text in the list first and make use of loops.

Comment: If you just want italic text, can you use `text(1, 2, 'Gorilla gorilla gorilla', font=3)` instead? That should easily vectorize.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `bquote` here instead of `substitute`; in addition to some other differences (I do not know them all), `bquote` supports `.(somevar)` replacement.

```r
L <- "hello world"
plot(1)
text(1, 1.1, bquote(.(L) * "    " * italic(.(L))))
```

[image: base plot with some italics]